# Wrap head text of longtable

Tags: tables, formatting, header-footer, longtable

I'm working on a long table and I want to wrap the text in head of the table. I found even if I use `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` then the text in head cannot be wrapped. However, if I just write the head without using these two commands, the text can be wrapped but they don't repeat at the beginning of each page. Is there any way to wrap the text in head while the head can repeat on each page?

This is the code of using the command to make the header. It can repeat on each page but the text cannot be wrapped:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for management of figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}  % for "\citet" and "\citep"
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}  % for long table
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}  % for wrapped text around tables or figures
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{p{1.8cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}}
        \caption{Improvements by using DPTP and fixed presets of all benchmark functions} \label{table:result_improvement}                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
        \toprule \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Benchmark \newline function}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Experi. setup}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Initial fitness}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Final fitness}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Improvements}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Percentage}} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{6}{c}
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\

        \hline \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Benchmark \newline function}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Experi. setup}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Initial fitness}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Final fitness}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Improvements}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Percentage}} \\ \hline
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
        \endfoot

        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        \multirow{11}{*}{C23}                                              & DPTP                                        & 26992.13                                      & 2693.673                                    & 24298.46                                   & 90.02\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 0                                    & 25789.55                                      & 2756.774                                    & 23032.78                                   & 89.31\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 1                                    & 26236.34                                      & 2676.916                                    & 23559.42                                   & 89.80\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 2                                    & 27330.98                                      & 2737.67                                     & 24593.31                                   & 89.98\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 3                                    & 25465.2                                       & 2735.844                                    & 22729.35                                   & 89.26\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 4                                    & 25977.27                                      & 2678.884                                    & 23298.38                                   & 89.69\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 5                                    & 25361.18                                      & 2702.239                                    & 22658.95                                   & 89.34\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 6                                    & 26466.49                                      & 2695.999                                    & 23770.49                                   & 89.81\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 7                                    & 26699.03                                      & 2767.44                                     & 23931.59                                   & 89.63\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 8                                    & 26699.03                                      & 2767.44                                     & 23931.59                                   & 89.63\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 9                                    & 27365.9                                       & 2695.156                                    & 24670.75                                   & 90.15\%                                 \\ \hline
        \multirow{11}{*}{C23}                                              & DPTP                                        & 26992.13                                      & 2693.673                                    & 24298.46                                   & 90.02\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 0                                    & 25789.55                                      & 2756.774                                    & 23032.78                                   & 89.31\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 1                                    & 26236.34                                      & 2676.916                                    & 23559.42                                   & 89.80\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 2                                    & 27330.98                                      & 2737.67                                     & 24593.31                                   & 89.98\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 3                                    & 25465.2                                       & 2735.844                                    & 22729.35                                   & 89.26\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 4                                    & 25977.27                                      & 2678.884                                    & 23298.38                                   & 89.69\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 5                                    & 25361.18                                      & 2702.239                                    & 22658.95                                   & 89.34\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 6                                    & 26466.49                                      & 2695.999                                    & 23770.49                                   & 89.81\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 7                                    & 26699.03                                      & 2767.44                                     & 23931.59                                   & 89.63\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 8                                    & 26699.03                                      & 2767.44                                     & 23931.59                                   & 89.63\%                                 \\
                                                                           & Preset 9                                    & 27365.9                                       & 2695.156                                    & 24670.75                                   & 90.15\%                                 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The header does not wrap:
[image]

This is the code of not using the command, the text can be wrapped but head does not repeat:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for management of figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}  % for "\citet" and "\citep"
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}  % for long table
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}  % for wrapped text around tables or figures
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{p{1.8cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}}
        \caption{Improvements by using DPTP and fixed presets of all benchmark functions} 
        \label{table:result_improvement} \\
        Benchmark function    & Experi. setup & Initial fitness & Final fitness & Improvements & Improvement percentage    \\ \hline
        \multirow{11}{*}{C23} & DPTP          & 26992.13        & 2693.673      & 24298.46     & 90.02\%                   \\
                              & Preset 0      & 25789.55        & 2756.774      & 23032.78     & 89.31\%                   \\
                              & Preset 1      & 26236.34        & 2676.916      & 23559.42     & 89.80\%                   \\
                              & Preset 2      & 27330.98        & 2737.67       & 24593.31     & 89.98\%                   \\
                              & Preset 3      & 25465.2         & 2735.844      & 22729.35     & 89.26\%                   \\
                              & Preset 4      & 25977.27        & 2678.884      & 23298.38     & 89.69\%                   \\
                              & Preset 5      & 25361.18        & 2702.239      & 22658.95     & 89.34\%                   \\
                              & Preset 6      & 26466.49        & 2695.999      & 23770.49     & 89.81\%                   \\
                              & Preset 7      & 26699.03        & 2767.44       & 23931.59     & 89.63\%                   \\
                              & Preset 8      & 26699.03        & 2767.44       & 23931.59     & 89.63\%                   \\
                              & Preset 9      & 27365.9         & 2695.156      & 24670.75     & 90.15\%                   \\ \hline
        \multirow{11}{*}{C23} & DPTP          & 26992.13        & 2693.673      & 24298.46     & 90.02\%                   \\
                              & Preset 0      & 25789.55        & 2756.774      & 23032.78     & 89.31\%                   \\
                              & Preset 1      & 26236.34        & 2676.916      & 23559.42     & 89.80\%                   \\
                              & Preset 2      & 27330.98        & 2737.67       & 24593.31     & 89.98\%                   \\
                              & Preset 3      & 25465.2         & 2735.844      & 22729.35     & 89.26\%                   \\
                              & Preset 4      & 25977.27        & 2678.884      & 23298.38     & 89.69\%                   \\
                              & Preset 5      & 25361.18        & 2702.239      & 22658.95     & 89.34\%                   \\
                              & Preset 6      & 26466.49        & 2695.999      & 23770.49     & 89.81\%                   \\
                              & Preset 7      & 26699.03        & 2767.44       & 23931.59     & 89.63\%                   \\
                              & Preset 8      & 26699.03        & 2767.44       & 23931.59     & 89.63\%                   \\
                              & Preset 9      & 27365.9         & 2695.156      & 24670.75     & 90.15\%                   \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

the text can be wrapped but head does not repeat:
[image]

Comment: It is an annoying habit not to provide a working code, and let the people that try to help figure out what packages to load, etc.

Comment: A `c` type column (in the `\multicolumn` in this case) will not allow text to wrap. You need a `p{..}` type column for that.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Sorry, I have added a working code environment.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum  Solved! I used ```p{...}``` in ```\multicolumn``` line and it workks, thank you!

Comment: you do not need multicolumn or p as you already declared this column as a p column at the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the centering and also line breaking I would recommend

```
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Benchmark \newline function}}
```

(2cm seems to fit better than 1.8cm)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what the ">" in front of ```"\centering``` works for?

Comment: It means that `\centering` is placed before the entry. See the documentation of the `array` package.